# Repaint issue with JPanel inside another JPanel 

Tags: java, jpanel, repaint, redraw

I'm drawing shapes inside this `JPanel`, which is also inside another main `JPanel`. At `repaint()` it only draws the shapes for one millisecond and then they disappear. They don't stay painted, why?

My `paintComponent` method is something like this

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (int i = 0; i < reportElements.size(); i++) {
        this.reportElements.get(i).display((Graphics2D) pageComponents.get(i).getGraphics());

    }
}
```

When the parent is a `JEditorPane` with `setEditable()` enabled, it works and we can see the shapes but when it's a `JPanel`, after a millisecond all I see is empty panels.

Comment: did you try overriding **paint(Graphics g)** instead that **paintComponent(Graphics g)**?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion jack, but that's not the problem. i think i tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in this case what happens to those
>   pageComponents, the small JPanels? The
>   parent panel is not gonna draw the
>   shapes on them is it?

I'm not sure I undertand your comment. Your main panel should contain child panels. The child panels should be added to the main panel using a layout manager. Then when Swing decides to repaint the main panel, it will also repaint all the child panels and in turn the child panels will repaint there shapes.

For what its worth [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) has a working example of drawing shapes on a panel.

Comment: what I mean is I'd like the shapes to not be on the main panel but the children, so that when I change one of those small JPanels's coordinates the drawing would also change position, or when I remove one of the JPanels, the drawing would also disintegrate(BG-SoA).

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I described, the paintComponent() method of each child panel is customized. Then when you add the child panel to the parent the painting of the child is done automatically.

Comment: I understand, then to customize their paint I guess I need to create a seperate class for the child panel as well? Cause I just created objects of JPanel before. no wait wouldn't that lead to the same problem in the first place?

Comment: well it worked. now, eea which answer should I tick :) everyone gave good feedback thanks.

Comment: @Halo check out the concept of composite design pattern in case you still have not got around your mind of why this thing works the way it is.

Answer (score 3):

you should paint to the Graphics object of the JPanel for it to be permanent... In your example, that is the `Graphics g`...

Comment: but wait a sec. in this case what happens to those pageComponents, the small JPanels? The parent panel is not gonna draw the shapes on them is it? then are they useless now?

Answer (score 2):

[ultrajohn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191064/ultrajohn) is dead on. You need to use the `Graphics` you have been passed. Read on for the why...

Java 1.6 introduced the `RepaintManager` that supports the optimizing of repaint requests. It has  some  subtle effects on painting.

In this case, you're working with multiple Graphics2D objects: the `g` passed into `paintComponent` and the value returned by the `getGraphics` call.

The repaint manager has handed you `g` on which to paint. Note: this does not paint on the screen, but on a temporary buffer (assuming the default double buffering).

In the `paintComponent` call you are painting to the graphics obtained from `getGraphics` of the various components. This is bypassing the repaint manager and painting directly to  the unbuffered display.

When `paintChildren` returns, the `RepaintManager` kicks in to handle updating the double buffer. It paints the blank temporary buffer over the displayed buffer, effectively erasing what was painted through the graphics object obtained from `getGraphics`

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller, for a sec I thought you said that I was dead... :)

Comment: Sorry @ultrajohn, my mistake! I was fooled by the 8-year RTT on your packets ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `paintChildren` or `paintBorder` overdraws whatever you've drawn in your method. Perhaps try overriding `paint` instead. There you have full control over what will be painted on the component, and you can decide yourself whether to further call `paintComponent`, `paintChildren` or `paintBorder` at all.